# Without creating activity open new screen in android

Tags: android

I just want to know it is possible to open new screem without creating activity. (Means I don't want to create activity and open screen). I don't want to use dialog.

EX.
I have Two class. 1st is my main activity with one button, from where I want to open new screen.
And 2nd is my custom class which extends linear layout and add two textview controls and back button.

So now in my main activity, I click on button to show my 2nd class in new screen. And when click on back from 2nd screen it will appear 1st screen again.

Please any have any idea please share his/her knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And why can't you just use two Activities?

Comment: No, I just want to use only one activity. Second class is my custom controller. Which contains some controls such as textview, button, etc.

Comment: Right, but why can't you put those controls in another activity?

Comment: you can use ContentView utilizing the same activity, or use inflater on the current activity from the xml file(layout)

Answer (score 2):

In your main activity you can remove the views added and add the new views to your layout. If you don't want to remove your main activity views you can still do it by addcontent view.

Answer (score 0):

use a `ViewPager` for controlling which screen is displayed. also override onBackPressed() to control the back button.

follow this [post](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537) for a `ViewPager` example.

Answer (score 0):

Store your layouts into hashmap.When you click the button get the respective view from the hashmap and set that view to the setContentView(yourView);